# implement a logic in circuit without using a micro-controller

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic

Given a sensor and push button output I need to implement this logic without using a microcontroller

If the sensor is ON the output is ON and stays ON till the push button is ON then output goes back to OFF

```
sensor(j)   push-button(k)  Q(t+1)
0           0            Q(no change)
0           1            0(reset)
1           0            1(set)
1           1            Q'
```

The    closest i've came to it is jk flip flop but it won't be ideal so I was looking for an  alternative or at least how to implement it

Comment: This seriously  sounds like a homework project. You will have to provide details of the schematic of what you have actually tried and then ask a specific question about that. Folks at this site are not here to design your circuit for you or to do your homework.

Comment: have a look through the WIkipedia [flip-flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)) article and see if anything looks helpful.

Comment: Use relay ladder logic.  Piece of cake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flip flops are hard to be stable without using a clock so i decided to use microcontroller to get it done

Comment: I have no problem with your using a microcontroller, but your answer does not meet the constraints you imposed in the question.